# MinGW gfortran compilation error: "Unrecognized option '-plugin' "

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, fortran, mingw, gfortran

I'm trying to get a Fortran compiler up and running on my windows machine but I just can't get it to work for some reason. I've installed the "Basic setup" part of the latest MinGW and I'm trying to compile a simple "Hello world" program but I'm getting the following error message:

```
C:\MinGW>gfortran -o executable Hello.f90
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '-plugin'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: use the --help option for usage information
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the source file for reference:

Hello.f90

```
program Hello
    write (*,*) 'Hello, world!'
end program Hello
```

Does anyone have any clue what the issue might be?

edit:
    version information

```
C:\Users\Angel>c:/mingw/bin/ld.exe --version
GNU ld version 2.17.50 20060824
Copyright 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.  This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

Comment: P.S. If you know of any other working way that I could get Fortran to compile on windows I would greatly appreciate the information

Comment: Please post the output of command `c:/mingw/bin/ld.exe --version`. Add this information in the body of your question, not in comments.

Comment: A bit of searching revealed https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2015-06/msg00079.html One possible reason is a haskell install or an older install of gcc or gfortran.

Comment: @Pierre I don't have a Haskell install on my machine but I did however end up having an duplicate old version of minGW in a codeblocks installation. I removed it just in case but it didn't seem to help the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linker (binutils `ld`v2.17.50) is too old for your `gfortran` frontend,
(`v8.2.0`). The `-plugin` option which `gfortran` is passing to `ld` in the
the linkage boilerplate is supported only since `ld` v2.21.51.

This means you don't have a coherent `gfortran` toolchain. Binutils v2.17.50 was released June 2007; GCC 8.2 in July 2018.
Possibly you have installed `gfortran` 8.2 on top of an antiquated MinGW release.

You might be well-advised to remove your MinGW installation completely and replace
it with the [current mingw-w64 release](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), which
you may [download at Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/).